# Updating input field with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with inputs that are summed vertically and horizontally using JQuery. The bottom row totals the first two columns and is then supposed to sum their totals in `<input type="text" name="grand_total" class="numbox_dark" readonly>` input. The problem is the `<input type="text" name="grand_total" class="numbox_dark" readonly>` doesn't update because there is no user interaction with the "total_sales1" and "total_sales2" inputs.

The script I use looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
        var $div = $(this).closest('tr');
        var postpaid = parseFloat($div.find(':input[name*="_postpaid"]').val(),10),
            hup = parseFloat($div.find(':input[name*="_hup"]').val(),10);

        if (isNaN(postpaid)) postpaid = 0;
        if (isNaN(hup)) hup = 0;

        var v = '';

        if (!isNaN(postpaid) && !isNaN(hup)){
            v = (postpaid + hup);
        }
        $div.find(':input[name*="_total"]').val(v.toString());
    });
});
```

The table looks like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>Category 1</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="category1_sales1" class="numbox">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="category1_sales2" class="numbox">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="category1_total" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Category 2</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="category2_sales1" class="numbox">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="category2_sales2" class="numbox">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="category2_total" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="total_sales1" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="total_sales2" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="grand_total" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I get "grand_total" to update as entries are made on the top two rows?

Comment: all solved for you below. there were several changes/additions needed. fiddle included with working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here is a jsFiddle with your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/nSLpz/

You needed an `updateTotals` function, as shown... hastily written but very easy to optimize further:

```
function updateTotals() {
    var sales1 = 0
    var sales2 = 0

    $(':input[name*="_sales1"]').each(function(){
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) sales1 += 0;
        else sales1 += parseFloat($(this).val())
    });

    $(':input[name*="_sales2"]').each(function(){
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) sales2 += 0;
        else sales2 += parseFloat($(this).val())
    });

    $('#total_sales1').val(sales1)
    $('#total_sales2').val(sales2)

    $('#grand_total').val(sales1+sales2)
}
```

This is called during your `bind` call, at the end: `updateTotals();`

This also required a change to the HTML... specifically the last row:

```
<tr id="totals">
    <td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="total_sales1" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="total_sales2" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="grand_total" class="numbox_dark" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
```